how to remove interlinked nodes in a neo4j graph?
I have the following graph that is a result of a query which is as follows:
MATCH p=(parent:FEATURE)-[*]->(gap:GAP)

WHERE parent.name = "Update Profile" AND ANY(substring IN ["CSRF", "manipulate"] 
WHERE gap.name CONTAINS substring)

 RETURN p,

   apoc.coll.removeAll(

     [node IN NODES(p) | [fp = (node:RULE)<-[:REQUIRE]-(f:FACT) | fp ]],

     [[]]) AS factPaths


What I want to do is remove the nodes GENERIC_FEAT, Rule, attack category and attack vector. I want to connect Feature -> Threat -> GAP <- FACT.
is it possible to connect the graph like that while making a query to return the graph? I want to modify my query to return a graph with the following patternFeature -> Threat -> GAP <- FACT instead of the long graph shown in the picture.

Do you want to just return Feature, Threat, GAP and FACT nodes from each path? Or do you actually want to insert relationships between Feature and Threat, Threat and GAP, and GAP and FACT?

@FinbarGood i want to return Feature, Threat, GAP and FACT nodes from each path and insert a virtual relationship between them

Here is a query that drops the relationships and nodes that you don't want to see and replaces them with virtual relationships between the nodes that are left:
MATCH (fe:FEATURE)-->+(t:THREAT)-->+(g:GAP)
MATCH (g)<--+(fa:FACT)
WITH collect(DISTINCT [fe, t]) + collect(DISTINCT [t, g]) AS hases,
    collect(DISTINCT [fa, g]) AS requireses
WITH 
    COLLECT {
        WITH hases
        UNWIND hases AS pair
        RETURN [
            pair[0], 
            apoc.create.vRelationship(pair[0], 'HAS', {}, pair[1]), 
            pair[1]
        ] AS tuple
    } +
    COLLECT {
        WITH requireses
        UNWIND requireses AS pair
        RETURN [
            pair[0], 
            apoc.create.vRelationship(pair[0], 'REQUIRES', {}, pair[1]), 
            pair[1]
        ] AS tuple
    } AS tuples
UNWIND tuples AS tuple
RETURN tuple[0], tuple[1], tuple[2]

Here is roughly what the results would look like in Browser given the data above:

There are two MATCH clauses because the GAP <-- FACT paths need to re-traverse parts of the Threat --> GAP paths, and Cypher requires relationships be unique within a result emitted from MATCH.
The collect() + DISTINCT are there to drop all the duplicate relationships that would otherwise be created between the nodes, due to there being multiple paths re-traversing the same subpaths.

hi. this ends with no results

I created data based on the image in your question. Running my suggested query produced the result you see here. Perhaps if you could share a snippet of your data, I can spot why it returns no results.

my dataset is large. how do i share it here?

I was just suggesting sharing a small sample, not the whole graph.

I had to made a few adjustments regarding naming conventions and the query worked perfect. Thanks
